# Double or integer? What to use with BIG or SMALL data types?

Tags: vb.net, types

I have a value of: "2.54334881002458E-37" and i keep getting "overflow" exception when i'm using a double.

what should i use to make this work?

Thank you

code snippet:

```
Dim curries, act, cat As Double
 For Each dataRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
            curries = dataRow("Activity")
```

getting the error when i try to assign Activity to curries.

but "activity" is a string in the database....

Comment: That's a seriously small number. How about just using 0? ;-)

Comment: @Jon - i can't use 0, it's for a very specific calculation :)

Comment: @xnum. It was a joke! (hence the smiley)

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a string to a double?

Comment: If activity is a string you will need to `CType` it or `DirectCast` it to a double / decimal / integer or wahtever data type you end up using, see my answer below.

Comment: @xrum - so what was the issue and how did you resolve it?

Comment: i made it a decimal. and put some "dbnull.value" checks in. thanks!

Comment: If Not dataRow("Activity") Is DBNull.Value Then
                curries = dataRow("Activity")
            Else
                curries = 0
            End If

Comment: @Smudge202 -And that comes with time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double is already 64 bits worth of floating point number.
Can you post code where you are getting this overflow?
Decimal might be worth a shot, but you have to post code so that we can understand the issues you are encountering.

Based on your edit in your post, why are you storing numbers as strings in your database?  That is a definite no no...unless you are not doing any sort of arithmaetic operation only then can you store them as varchar / string.

Give us a sample of what the data looks like...I think your issue stems from not converting the string to a decimal, if activity is a string convert it using `DirectCast` or `CType` (cast the value):

`curries = CType(datarow("Activity"), Double)`

Comment: I prefer to use curries = datarow(Of Double)("Activity") which returns type Double, although, checking for null first might also be in order.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway - So does directcast and ctype.

Answer (score 2):

Change your unit of measure, so that you're not working in 10^-37 of whatever it is you're dealing with. This problem just screams "I'm not solving this in the appropriate domain."

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), Double should have no problem at all with your number:

Range:

-1.79769313486231570E+308 through -4.94065645841246544E-324 † for negative values;
4.94065645841246544E-324 through 1.79769313486231570E+308 † for positive values

Comment: His issue isn't about whether it can actually store the value, I assume his issue is more along the lines of storing a string into a decimal / double value.  He will need to `DirectCast` or `CType` the value before assigining it to a `double`.

Comment: He updated the question since I typed this. The Example wasn't there - just the value and the statement that there was an overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

and if the need to have large numbers and precise I suggest the use of decimal numbers, more information here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx

Bye